# Pushing the bar from different points, which gives a better spin?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity

If we apply force for a short time, which one makes a better turn around the circle?

I know that normally pushing from a far is a better spin because of torque. But i think there may be different results, here the center of gravity is in the middle bar but the axis of rotation is at a different point (object mass is evenly distributed)

The circle is fixed, and the rod and the circle are not connected.

[image: drawing_example]